# Python/Django OOP modify the following code to show get/set and constructor

Tags: python, django

**Case.** I want to modify and add the following behavior to the code below (it's a context processor):

**After checking if a user is authenticated check the last time the balance was updated (cookie maybe) if it was updated in the last 5 mins do nothing, else get the new balance as normal.**

```
def get_balance(request):

     if request.user.is_authenticated():
        balance = Account.objects.get(user=request.user).balance
     else:
        balance = 0

     return {'account_balance': balance}
```

**HOWEVER:**

I want to **learn a little more about OOP in Django/Python** can some modify the example to achieve my goal include the use of:

**Property:** I come from Java, I want to **set** and **get**, it makes more sense to me. get balance if does not exist else create new one.

**Constructor method:** In Python I think I have to change this to a class and use init right?

UPDATE:

To use a construct I first think I need to create a class, I'm assuming this is ok using  as a context processor in Django to do something like this:

```
class BalanceProcessor(request):

    _balance = Account.objects.get(user=request.user).balance

    @property
    def get_balance(self):
       return  return {'account_balance': _balance}

    @setter???
```

Comment: please, fix your indentation. It is not anoptional thing for Python code.

Comment: @jsbueno Typed into question so forgot indention, fixed :)

Comment: I keep trying to answer your question correctly, but you keep editing it ;) Btw, the "request" variable in parentheses next to "BalanceProcessor" is what you would be subclassing... it's not an argument.

Comment: @JoeLinux no more edits :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is **not Java**. In Python you don't create classes for no reason. Classes are for when you have data you want to encapsulate with code. In this case, there is no such thing: you simply get some data and return it. A class would be of no benefit here whatsoever.

In any case, even if you do create a class, once again **Python is not Java**, and you don't create getters and setters on properties unless you actually need to do some processing when you get and set. If you just want to access an instance attribute, then you simply access it.

Finally, your proposed code will not work for two reasons. Firstly, you are trying to inherit from `request`. That makes no sense: you should inherit from `object` unless you are subclassing something. Secondly, how are you expecting your class to be instantiated? Context processors are usually functions, and that means Django is expecting a callable. If you give the class as the context processor, then calling it will instantiate it: but then there's nothing that will call the `get_balance` method. And your code will fail because Django will pass the `request` into the instantation (as it is expecting to do with a function) and your `__init__` doesn't expect that parameter.

It's fine to experiment with classes in Python, but a context processor is not the place for it.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Roseman, I still see the need for a getter and setter here. It allows me to get the balance and let the code set one if not created. I also see the need to change or modified the set balance method in the future. A setter makes more sense to me here. It future-proofs the code! Without doing this I don't see how I can change the code later without changing the calling methods here.

Comment: We don't "future-proof" with getters and setters: this is why Python has the `@property` decorator. But what would be the point of setting anything here? The context processor would be instantiated when the template is rendered, then immediately disposed. Nothing is persisted. Why would you set data?

Comment: I see thanks for taking the time to explain, this is what I need to learn. In terms of a context processor I see now why this makes no sense. @property is very interesting I tried to edit the code to make use of them (pretending it's not context processor)

Comment: @User7 : doing proper OO in Django requires a good understanding of both Python's object model (which is a bit peculiar when coming from most mainstream OOPLs) AND the objects lifecycle in Django. Also wrt/ properties (which are just a "general" application of the `descriptor` protocol), the moto is "don't use them until you need them" - and if you find yourself writing the same fget/fset implementation for a couple or more properties it might be time to roll your own custom `descriptor`.